# How to debug a incorrect module dependency in JBoss AS 7?

Tags: jboss, osgi, classloader, jboss7.x

I have a web app, which uses Sun's MSV library. All the classes for MSV are included in jars in the web app `WEB-INF/lib`. When deploying this app on JBoss 7, I get the following exception:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.sun.msv.datatype.xsd.AnyURIType
        at com.sun.msv.datatype.xsd.DatatypeFactory.getTypeByName(DatatypeFactory.java:195)
        at com.sun.msv.datatype.xsd.ngimpl.DataTypeLibraryImpl.getType(DataTypeLibraryImpl.java:32)
        at com.sun.msv.datatype.xsd.ngimpl.DataTypeLibraryImpl.createDatatypeBuilder(DataTypeLibraryImpl.java:36)
        at com.sun.msv.reader.trex.ng.DataState.startSelf(DataState.java:58)
        at com.sun.msv.reader.State.init(State.java:153)
        at com.sun.msv.reader.GrammarReader.pushState(GrammarReader.java:576)
        at com.sun.msv.reader.SimpleState.startElement(SimpleState.java:71)
        at org.xml.sax.helpers.XMLFilterImpl.startElement(XMLFilterImpl.java:527)
        at com.sun.msv.reader.trex.TREXBaseReader.startElement(TREXBaseReader.java:184)
        at com.sun.msv.reader.trex.ng.RELAXNGReader.startElement(RELAXNGReader.java:524)
        at com.sun.msv.reader.trex.ng.comp.RELAXNGCompReader.startElement(RELAXNGCompReader.java:197)
        at orbeon.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(AbstractSAXParser.java:497)
        at orbeon.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractXMLDocumentParser.emptyElement(AbstractXMLDocumentParser.java:180)
        at orbeon.apache.xerces.xinclude.XIncludeHandler.emptyElement(XIncludeHandler.java:1024)
        at orbeon.apache.xerces.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:275)
        at orbeon.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDispatcher.dispatch(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:1654)
        at orbeon.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:324)
        at orbeon.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:845)
        at orbeon.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:768)
        at orbeon.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:108)
        at orbeon.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1201)
        at com.sun.msv.reader.util.GrammarLoader._loadSchema(GrammarLoader.java:514)
        at com.sun.msv.reader.util.GrammarLoader.parse(GrammarLoader.java:325)
        at com.sun.msv.reader.util.GrammarLoader.loadSchema(GrammarLoader.java:189)
        at com.sun.msv.verifier.jarv.TheFactoryImpl.parse(TheFactoryImpl.java:42)
        at com.sun.msv.verifier.jarv.FactoryImpl.compileSchema(FactoryImpl.java:98)
```

It complains that it cannot find the class `com.sun.msv.datatype.xsd.AnyURIType`, but that class is present in one of the jars. I am assuming some of those classes on the stack trace were "incorrectly" picked up from a module that comes from JBoss, thus loaded from another class loader, rather than from a jar in the web app's `WEB-INF/lib`. But which one can it be? (The `orbeon.apache.xerces` you see there is a re-rooted version of Apache Xerces, so we can be sure it has been loaded from the web app jars.) I have seen that I can exclude some modules in the `jboss-deployment-structure.xml`, as follows, but which on should I exclude? How to find out?

```
<jboss-deployment-structure>
    <ear-subdeployments-isolated>true</ear-subdeployments-isolated>
    <deployment>
        <exclusions>
            <module name="com.sun.xml.bind"/>
            <module name="org.codehaus.woodstox"/>
            <module name="org.codehaus.jackson.jackson-xc"/>
        </exclusions>
    </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

Comment: You may be able to get help in the jboss community [forum](http://community.jboss.org/) since AS7 is brand new. Many of the JBoss core developers are very active in the community site.

Comment: Thank you for the advice. I posted the question on http://community.jboss.org/thread/173836, and will follow up here if I find a solution to this issue through the JBoss forum

Answer (score 0):

HI I am not understanding your actual configuration but this is because of your module configuration in xml configuration file. I also got this kind of error but i resolved it by provided module to server.So You have to install your library as a module in your server.

**Add a module**
i.Under the root directory of the application server, is a directory called modules. Create your own module
For E.g. jboss-7.0.0./modules/com/mysql/main
ii. Now you need to define your module with a module.xml file, and the actual jar file that contains your database driver in the created folder.

```
  Modules
   +---com
   ¦   +---codehaus
   ¦   ¦    +---main
   ¦   ¦    +-------module.xml 
   ¦   ¦    +------<your jar file>
```

The contents of module.xml should be as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.0" name="<*module name*>">
 <resources>
 <resource-root path="<*jar name*>"/>
 <!-- Insert resources here -->
</resources>
<dependencies>
<module name="javax.api"/>
 <module name="javax.transaction.api"/>
</dependencies>
 </module>
```

Dependencies are used for declaring your module dependencies on other module.